# Is Typescript 4.0+ capable of functions using mapped variadic tuple types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript4.0

As an example, say I have a simple function which maps a variadic number of things to an array of objects like `{ a: value }`.

```js
const mapToMyInterface = (...things) => things.map((thing) => ({ a: thing}));
```

Typescript in not yet able to infer a strong type for the result of this function yet:

```js
const mapToMyInterface = mapToInterface(1, 3, '2'); // inferred type{ a: any }[]
```

First, I define a type that describes an array mapped to observables:

```js
type MapToMyInterface<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<infer U> ? { a: U } : { a: T[K] }
}
```

Now I update my function:

```js
const mapToMyInterface = <T extends any[]>(...things: T): MapToMyInterface<T> => things.map((thing) => ({ a: thing}));
```

So far, Typescript is not happy. The return expression of the function is highlighted with the error "TS2322: Type '{ a: any; }[]' is not assignable to type 'MapToMyInterface'"

Obviously, the parameter `thing` needs to be explicitly typed in the mapping function. But I don't know of a way to say "the nth type", which is what I need.

That is to say, neither marking `thing` as a `T[number]` or even doing the following works:

```js
const mapToMyInterface = <T extends any[], K = keyof T>(...things: T): MapToMyInterface<T> => things.map((thing: T[K]) => of(thing));
```

Is is possible for this to work in Typescript?

EDIT after @jcalz's answer:
For posterity, I wanted to post the original motivation for my question, and the solution I was able to get from @jcalz's answer.

I was trying to wrap an RxJs operator, `withLatestFrom`, to lazily evaluate the observables passed into it (useful when you may be passing in an the result of a function that starts an ongoing subscription somewhere, like `store.select` does in NgRx).

I was able to successfully assert the return value like so:

```js
export const lazyWithLatestFrom = <T extends Observable<unknown>[], V>(o: () => [...T]) =>
  concatMap(value => of(value).pipe(withLatestFrom(...o()))) as OperatorFunction<
    V,
    [V, ...{ [i in keyof T]: TypeOfObservable<T[i]> }]
  >;
```

Comment: Could you make the code here a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to demonstrate the issue?  Right now you're using `Observable` and `of` which depends on a third-party library.  If your question is dependent on this library, it should probably be tagged as such.  If not, you might want to remove the dependence by providing a toy implementation of something similar.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://tsplay.dev/1WGXKw) is what you're looking for?  The built-in typing for `Array.prototype.map()` is not going to do anything higher-order by itself, but you can certainly give it an appropriate mapped tuple type yourself.

Comment: @jcalz they are both from the 'rxjs' library, but `of` seems to return type `any` making this strict return type futile.  And also it seems like `of` is deprecated.

Comment: @jcalz @Linda Paise I've updated my question to use a made-up object instead of `Observable` to make the content of my question clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a generic function `wrap()` which takes a value of type `T` and returns a value of type `{a: T}`, as in your example:

```
function wrap<T>(x: T) {
    return ({ a: x });
}
```

If you just make a function which takes an array `things` and calls `things.map(wrap)`, you'll get a weakly typed function, as you noticed:

```
const mapWrapWeaklyTyped = <T extends any[]>(...things: T) => things.map(wrap);
// const mapWrapWeaklyTyped: <T extends any[]>(...things: T) => {a: any}[]
```

This completely forgets about the individual types that went in and their order, and you just an array of `{a: any}`.  It's true enough, but not very useful:

```
const weak = mapWrapWeaklyTyped(1, "two", new Date());
try {
    weak[2].a.toUpperCase(); // no error at compile time, but breaks at runtime
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // weak[2].prop.toUpperCase is not a function 
}
```

Darn, the compiler didn't catch the fact that `2` refers to the *third* element of the array which is a wrapped `Date` and not a wrapped `string`.  I had to wait until runtime to see the problem.

---

If you look at the [standard TypeScript library's typing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/36f08350c95b8801d2a1334cd700d916f07cc298/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1349) for `Array.prototype.map()`, you'll see why this happens:

```
interface Array<T> {
  map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}
```

When you call `things.map(wrap)`, the compiler infers a single `U` type, which is unfortunately going to be `{a: any}`, because if `things` is of type `T extends any[]`, all the compiler knows about the elements of `things` is that they are assignable to `any`.

There's really no good *general* typing you could give to `Array.prototype.map()` that will handle the case where the `callbackfn` argument does different things to different types of input.  That would require higher kinded types like [type constructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_constructor), which TypeScript doesn't currently support directly (see [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) for a relevant feature request).

---

But in the case where you have a specific generic type for your `callbackfn`, (e.g., `(x: T) => {a: T}` ), you can manually describe the specific type transformation on a tuple or array using [mapped array/tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

Here it is:

```
const mapWrapStronglyTyped = <T extends any[]>(...things: T) => things.map(wrap) as
    { [K in keyof T]: { a: T[K] } };
// const mapWrapStronglyTyped: 
//   <T extends any[]>(...things: T) => { [K in keyof T]: {a: T[K]; }; }
```

What we're doing here is just iterating over each (numeric) index `K` of the `T` array, and taking the `T[K]` element at that index and mapping it to `{a: T[K] }`.

**Note that because the standard library's typing of `map()` does not anticipate this particular generic mapping function, you have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to have it type check.  If you're only concerned about the compiler's inability to verify this without a type assertion, this is really about the best you can do without higher kinded types in TypeScript.**

You can test it out on the same example as before:

```
const strong = mapWrapStronglyTyped(1, "two", new Date());
try {
    strong[2].a.toUpperCase(); // compiler error, Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'Date'
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); //  strong[2].prop.toUpperCase is not a function 
}
// oops, I meant to do this instead!
console.log(strong[1].a.toUpperCase()); // TWO
```

Now the compiler catches the mistake, and tells me that `Date` objects don't have a `toUpperCase` method.  Hooray!

---

Your version of the mapping,

```
type MapToMyInterface<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<infer U> ? { a: U } : { a: T[K] }
}
```

is a little weird because you're doing the mapping *twice*; unless you're passing in arrays of arrays, there's no reason to check `T[K]` for whether or not it's an array itself.  `T` is the array, and `K` is the index of it.  So I'd say just return `{a: T[K]}` unless I'm missing something important.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAKgPgAoAPALkVwEpEBvAWAChFnFUBTKEVJQmxdcsUQBfSgG5GwxowgIAzlEQBbLAHUMmVW3QBrADYBPXAcxsAJogC8iPIjbEobMGbn8wBgNoBdIgDp-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)

Answer (score 1):

Can you enter an arbitrary number of arguments of different types and get back an array of `Observables` with those types in the same order? **No.**  You can't map a type based on the specific numeric keys.

Can you enter those same arbitrary arguments and get back an array of `Observables` with the union of those types? **Yes.**

```
type Unpack<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : T;

const mapToObservable = <T extends any[]>(...things: T): Observable<Unpack<T>>[] => things.map((thing) => of(thing));

const mapped: Observable<string | number>[] = mapToObservable(1, 3, "2");
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/jwgK9w)

**Edit:** I spoke too soon and it actually **is** possible to get the return types in the same order, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672504/how-to-map-a-tuple-to-another-tuple-type-in-typescript-3-0).

This return type gives you the return that you want

```
type MapToMyInterface<T extends any[]> = any[] & {
  [K in keyof T]: {a: T[K]};
} & {length: T['length']};
```

But the type that is returned from `array.map()` is not assignable to it (for the reasons which @jcalz just explained), so you have to assert that your return type is correct using `as`.

```
const mapToMyInterface = <T extends any[]>(...things: T): MapToMyInterface<T> => things.map((thing) => ({ a: thing})) as MapToMyInterface<T>;

const mapped = mapToMyInterface(1, 3, "2");
const [one, three, two] = mapped; // gets each element correctly
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/lWYyrW)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I feared. That's why some RxJs operators still have a bunch of function declarations to give strong typing for the first six params.

Comment: I was trying to write an operator that wrapped `withLatestFrom` but I'm gonna have to follow the same typings RxJs is doing today to achieve what I want, I think.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672504/how-to-map-a-tuple-to-another-tuple-type-in-typescript-3-0

Comment: I'll edit my answer but I don't understand what you are trying to do with the `T[K] extends Array<infer U> ? { a: U } : { a: T[K] }` because your actual function isn't checking if each entry is an array or not, it returns {a: T[K]} regardless.

Comment: The problem isn't generating a type that transforms each element from the original- both my solution and the solution in the answer of the question you linked achieve that.

My problem is that Typescript does not believe the function written for `mapToMyInterface` conforms to the return type.