# Why is it that, when mapping over the ConstructorParameters of a generic constructor, Typescript is no longer certain it is a tuple?

Tags: typescript

Given the below

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type MakeFirstUndefined<T extends unknown[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: I extends "0" ? undefined : T[I]
}

type FilterUndefined<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [] ? [] :
    T extends [infer H, ...infer R] ?
    H extends undefined ? FilterUndefined<R> : [H, ...FilterUndefined<R>] : T
```

When I apply it to a tuple, like below, I'm able to filter out the first element

```
type InputTuple = [number, string, object] 

type FirstUndefinedTuple = MakeFirstUndefined<InputTuple> // Type [undefined, string, object]
const outputFirstUndefinedSuccess: FirstUndefinedTuple = [undefined, 'a-string', {}]
const outputFirstUndefinedCorrectlyErrors: FirstUndefinedTuple = [1, 'a-string', {}]

type FirstItemFilteredOut = FilterUndefined<FirstUndefinedTuple> // Type [string, object]
const ouputFilteredSuccess: FilterUndefined<FirstUndefinedTuple> = ['a-string', {}]
const ouputFilteredCorrectlyErrors: FilterUndefined<FirstUndefinedTuple> =  ['a-string', {}, 'apple']
```

When I then apply the same concept to the `ConstructorParameters` of a specific `Constructor`. It works.

```
class MagicMonkey {
  constructor(public name: string, public tricks: string[]) {
    
  }
}

enum Color {
  BLUE,
  GREEN,
  PURPLE,
  RED,
  PINK,
}

class FlashyFlamingo {
  constructor(public name: string, public colors: Color[], wingSpan: number) {
    
  }
}

function createMagicMonkey(...args: FilterUndefined<MakeFirstUndefined<ConstructorParameters<typeof MagicMonkey>>>) {
  return new MagicMonkey('jack', ...args);
}

console.log(createMagicMonkey(['trick 1', 'trick 2']))

console.log(createMagicMonkey(['trick 1', 'trick 2'], 1000)) // Correct Error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

// Output:
// MagicMonkey: {
//   "name": "jack",
//   "tricks": [
//     "trick 1",
//     "trick 2"
//   ]
// } 

function createFlashyFlamingo(...args: FilterUndefined<MakeFirstUndefined<ConstructorParameters<typeof FlashyFlamingo>>>) {
  return new FlashyFlamingo('', ...args);
}

console.log(createFlashyFlamingo([Color.PINK, Color.PURPLE], 1000))
console.log(createFlashyFlamingo([Color.PINK, Color.PURPLE])) // Correct Error: Expected 2 aguments, but got one

// Output:
// FlashyFlamingo: {
//   "name": "",
//   "colors": [
//     4,
//     2
//   ]
// }
```

However if I attempt to generify it to any `Constructor`. It does not work.

```
function createGeneric<T extends Constructor<any>>(ctor: T, ...args: FilterUndefined<MakeFirstUndefined<ConstructorParameters<T>>>) {
   return new ctor('jack', ...args);
}

console.log(createGeneric(MagicMonkey, ['trick 1', 'trick 2']))

// Expected Ouput(same as createMagicMonkey): 
// MagicMonkey: {
//   "name": "jack",
//   "tricks": [
//     "trick 1",
//     "trick 2"
//   ]
// } 

console.log(createGeneric(FlashyFlamingo, [Color.PINK, Color.PURPLE], 1000))

// Expected Ouput(same as createFlashyFlamingo): 
// FlashyFlamingo: {
//   "name": "",
//   "colors": [
//     4,
//     2
//   ]
// }
```

I get the error: A rest "parameter must be of an array type"

As a test I removed the `FilterUndefined` part and even on just applying `MakeFirstUndefined` it still says "parameter must be of an array type". It's definitely a typle after applying `MakeFirstUndefined` and then `MakeFirstUndefined` as the example demonstrates.

I don't see how it could be anything else other than a tuple, seeing that `ConstructorParamters` returns a tuple. [Mapped tuple types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51679156/3304875) are a thing now, right?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4&ssl=19&ssc=102&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQDcAKEmhIUALJMA1hABiAS1QoAqggAmEAGbrKewlAgAPYBH1Io6BEoRwqCQSXIBvSVCh8ASSgTKBUQOEMoAgEuIKsbOygAIgAGJKgAfgd9IxMIPSguAkCBSQBfaVloDQAbG1RdA2NTc3jbPXtHZ1d3AU8oi2t2+0FM-wFC3z8BtsS+E0MIVCgACQAaKEZ6BaWoACUJjKm-FcGEjuymvIKs2vrG3Ja9ki4+dc3GO6WH5vy8Z4mRUq4GgAQQYHQwAI6DANWg5D4CHQAFsAEZLDYoVAmVgbOCogBWEGwE2Bcg0WmAP2u0Nh8IUyjUmh0OV+ZjBEKhMLhJAA9LyoiD-I4rqZMWgcXjCcTgKVMIgUFA4JDORSWaL8gBlLCYCBIThQNVU1k07n0vgix75DYAciYAFosTibRsvGU5QrgEqVZCjdTTPBUKgZTUQABRIO4A1+k2mWlwsj+ACMtodToQrBdUDdpRkQqNARsyK+wb0AHlIYmS-6-jGNXp4xA+QKCEK+OncUrpSTJPLkF7lar1HUllqdXro8P7rHa8zjfXG-0+HbHRKM1mc73Pd6hyPS4Hg9hQxHUFGuNWZ2Y61aG2b+v4Vx2N2VU2A6Tbc5gakx9QzWOpMHkRAwmzKY+yxLAcFQWgIVRGoAIoJhkQgLgOw2WD4MwKAJUwJQDQ7QQRB8aYoCmCoKkkWwUVgOAalwUC-AAIQAGW0MM1imABxPYwzDAA5Di-AABW0PYhOY9iph4gARQSoCEgI+IAaQ4iivx-exVG-JAAAsQC0pCcTgBioHAtBINwGD0DghCECQlCoDQqAMIQ+U6K0Lh4HcwQNioHFNTAHguCRNEliI45SL8cjpEMRxsHURBTODJgbEUf9AOAiAQAYZg2EnPcazMRQVGvNk8HgfsMGwXAhJYez6iQPAqgiP8AKApwsqILrwr8YNgHQVAEAoahWoyjrsptAkmFwrMthYdghCkNSFVoiB6Do1haEwZLUqYdL2rCWhlxwpQoCTLMbROqAACYPyEIRpHA1b1rgTbtogFKIDStrMuy47sVws6Lqu26BA2JMUkh+6oH5GigxlKAT1wLgw0sSBsHyM7uDYFFbGAJANlRStWDgL1rukWGK2ATkOEkWHvrGsIuB8WG-CSOzkKSLgkim3Ckg41nkhOpAuf8OmBRIpIrqTfnxZIoWAdO66kjlvxSlhspSMkWKEHixL3s+gzdP079kSMnL6Hm-Lp3rPBiqZSlCvKz0qqg2rUHqpZGuayIjb0gyzYzOAuqIHqoD6gahsoGg-ZNwyg9oG1Ztyhalsela4Ret6drUbT-dN82+C83B6AU5SNmL1BS9E8SwzBs7IZSe6t2QZ6Nq2nPY4DwvK9LxSVJo9zq7EiThBEWGDwRpHUBRtGZUx67uFYXGEHxwnidJpVKApgUqZpuWu4LoPmdV5IOYgUWkllwWkjcqNRb4U+-AAFgFiXpnJwX1YFTWYri4AEpDQNjYTitglgAVaEMRIFUILVXwDwEAXUtpQSKBsOaeVzxTm+JeO2jJSrXGdpVCyqB3aey0IQEOYdw4QH6oNYaNA4GJ15koZOls8qLXKOnVumd27AIgKAygANaAMwOllDY-0AKnXOraEGd0Hpy1RujGwBQKycloEgey3B7B8JEb9IQXA5a6PGifG+59L7MOvu-KWisRavCfgrSRZ1LHy2sY45Wp9v5QF-i3JAbdXodw+iAsBQjD7xxJuI3uZcB6RJrqPcGjdm4KLnhjFRMJITqM0T+JKgTc4-nzmEuA+jSKw1CYHEmJirFmO5s4tmd8tAP3sa-exn936eN-kAA)

**EDIT**: 2021/06/24 UTC 9:35 Update playground with usage examples and added `FilterUndefined` to the `createGeneric` function.

**EDIT**: 2021/06/24 UTC 16:08 Update playground to make it clear that the goal is to remove the first parameter type from any constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced `MakeFirstUndefined` with new one. It is hard to figure out for TS that

```js
type MakeFirstUndefined<T extends unknown[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: I extends "0" ? undefined : T[I]
}
```

produces an array.

```js
type TupleWithUndefined = [number, string, undefined, number];

// we need to infer constructor parameters
type Constructor<Args extends string[]> = new <R>(...args: [...Args]) => R;

type MakeFirstUndefined<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer _, ...infer Rest] ? [undefined, ...Rest] : T

type FilterUndefined<T extends unknown[]> =
    T extends [] ? [] :
    T extends [infer H, ...infer R] ?
    H extends undefined ? FilterUndefined<R> : [H, ...FilterUndefined<R>] : T


type InputTuple = [number, string, object]
type FilteredTuple = FilterUndefined<MakeFirstUndefined<InputTuple>> // [string, tuple] 

const error: FilteredTuple = [1, '2', {}]
const successful: FilteredTuple = ['2', {}]


class MagicMonkey {
    constructor(name: string, public tricks: string[]) {

    }
}

function create(...args: FilterUndefined<MakeFirstUndefined<ConstructorParameters<typeof MagicMonkey>>>) {
    return new MagicMonkey('jack', ...args);
}

function createGeneric<El extends string, Tuple extends El[]>(...args: MakeFirstUndefined<ConstructorParameters<Constructor<Tuple>>> & string[]) {
    return new MagicMonkey('jack', args);
}
```

Please, let me know if it works for you

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhA6gS2ACwKoDsAmEAZmrhPlALxQDaucAtgEYQBOANFAM7CukDmnOAWKlyneszYBdANwBYAFBLQkKAGEA9rh6s4AY2CbWAHgCCrflygQAHsAgFrugTWkA%20KlDIB3KCYAldwAKADpwgENLLgAuWnDQiytpAEoqTwCFZUVVaABZCIBrCAAxNFYePEISMnwTGBt7R3xrYULcTR9cN09qBrsHJ1pSIjYoAH1OBJGxgIgeaSgAflpharF8KfC5hag4mCUVcGgyxAdWKtFa%20sbBlqg2jq6eqiUod9hb5us3ZdpFmJvD79JpDGgzVhQAASW1CEKgAUWSyB7yhXyGayu5D%20p3Olxq5ECnjiNBhUASuLY%20I2RIBsEO2VyUAAkrgwHBgPAkNBqHRGCwONxeAJOJomAArCCGaRHNSU1jkLnILzy6nXArFMoVYBqwms9mchDIdyeAD0ptoLlwgigwCNEEWDP02h4NlYrGMcXlivtXhoAEZOAByABMQc4AG8AL4yxTOnTAbgGfTzLhEOCIL1oM5sH3cv2h8NQaOxp2ICJcawFfhofR5bTFEDFlFQeO6AxGVjBXARBgQOJWm3spiIWu2vj6QqxIV8a1uNIRhkfKBRpSr7Lp3CGNDaVsKiIOMKRaJZnMXEQEuoa0rlSoXmlaBN6QzGAAKUV7EHOXBMuU0RCgata3rXBGxNdwFxbBU7VYXBvAgPwgLrBsIBAYIg3FCJJyLBIoisFIsnXJRN23Xd9H3BwAHFHDYWsTAAUUQdF7kHTglWgAZvigRieiPUI8Ona8tTvdZrkfdsX1Yd9WE-b8THE3gO2Mep7XAqAADIZ1cVJm0UZdoLgWD4MQiIa2Q0DUPQzDsM4ASCLXJQgA)

`MagicMonkey` expect second argument to be `string[]` but I did not find any `stirng[]` constraints in your code. Maybe it worth adding?

**UPDATE**

```js
type Constructor<Args extends string[]> = new <R>(...args: [...Args]) => R;

class MagicMonkey<Trick extends string, Tricks extends Trick[]> {
    constructor(public name: string, public tricks: [...Tricks]) {

    }
}

function createGeneric<El extends string, Tuple extends El[]>(...args: ConstructorParameters<Constructor<Tuple>>) {
    return new MagicMonkey('jack', args);
}

const result2 = createGeneric('trick1') // MagicMonkey<string, ["trick1"]>
```

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with the with the createGeneric in my playground. Its should also filter by FilterUndefined.

Comment: SHould I apply `string[]` constraint?

Comment: Updated my playground with usage examples. I don't think you need string[], it should preserve the expected type for `tricks` parameter.

Comment: I made an update, could you pls explain why do you need `MakeFirstUndefined` ?

Comment: I want to filter out the first constructor argument, `name`,  so that it's not required for `createGeneric` because `createGeneric` defaults it. So I make it `undefined` and then filter out `undefined.` If there is a way to do it directly that would be better

Comment: Does my second example works for you? I did not used `UndefinedFilter` because function expects only `tricks` argument

Comment: No, my original `MakeFirstUndefined` definitely produces a tuple and the goal is to remove the first type from any constructors args tuple. I updated the playground to make it clear. `MagicMonkey` class is just an example.

Comment: Could you please provide an original example ? Does my solution works for you?