# Filter a type to only its non-nullable attributes

Tags: typescript

given this type

```
type HasOptionals = {
   name: string
   surname?: string
}
```

is it possible to generate a type that excludes any optional properties?

```
type example = OnlyRequired<HasOptionals> // { name: string }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with [key remapping](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#key-remapping-mapped-types):

```
type OnlyRequired<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K]
}
```

Now `OnlyRequired<HasOptionals>` is indeed `{ name: string; }`.

Comment: this exactly answers my question, thank you. I'm having a bit of difficulty translating the solution when T is an array. Could you help define `OnlyRequired` when T is `[name: string,  surname?: string | undefined]`

Comment: @stackoverfloweth "having difficulty" is a long way short of a [mre]!

Comment: @stackoverfloweth that's a _tuple_ type, and should probably be a separate question. It's probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51672504/3001761.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70840917/filter-tuple-type-to-only-required-properties