# Filter tuple type to only required properties

Tags: typescript

given this tuple type

```
type HasOptionalsInTuple = [name: string, surname?: string | undefined]
```

I would like to define a type that excludes optional values

```
type example2 = OnlyRequired<HasOptionalsInArray> // [name: string]
```

---

here's the closest type I have

```
type NoOptionalsInTuple<T extends [...any[]]> = {
  [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K]
}

type Applied = NoOptionalsInTuple<HasOptionalsInTuple> // length, toString, ...
```

also for context, this tuple I refer to is the result of `Parameters<T>`. So ultimately I'm looking for a version of `Parameters<T>` that excludes optional parameters

```
const method = (name: string, surname?: string) => {...}

type args = Parameters<typeof method> // [name: string, surname?: string | undefined]

type requiredArgs = RequiredParameters<typeof method> // [name: string]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAExgXhgCjAQ0QC4ZoAnASzAHMAaUgVzIMQH4TyrqBKLAPhgBvUJBAAbBADoxIankIJuAXwBQKqAE8ADghj4y1CFhgAFfQqgIyEADyadIAGbwkqNAID0HmAG0WCDihKGnoIJn92UiCuGAAfGAYwNARHKgQ0AF01e10yBABHBgo8tABBAyNsACUCopKzMgsrWxynFxR0T28-BUDg6iygA)

Comment: Did you try anything based on your previous question? Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51672504/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes I did, but I don't understand it

Comment: Then please [edit] to show that.

Comment: [This code](https://tsplay.dev/NBjPVN) is the version of the answer to the other question... note that this is just `[string]` and not `[name: string]`... preserving labels across tuples of different lengths is not always possible. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43020

Comment: btw, [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX7kLW) will preserve tuple labels, I think.  Not sure if I'd want to make that change to the other version, though.