# TypeScript: Conditional typing for input arrays

Tags: typescript

What I want to do, is have a function which takes an array of variables which can be one of a few `types`.

For each given `type`, the function's second argument (`callback`) will take an array of the counterpart `types`

`FooRequest` will map to `Foo`, `BarRequest`, to `Bar`, etc.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAShAjgVwgZ2FAvFAbwCgpSoB9YAQwHMAuKAcgDMFGAaIgXyKNEigAhKgCdk6LDnzEyFavSYAjUR269%200ACJoxqDNjyESZSrQaMAJjtU8%204aAEEANk-H7gmQ-CR7JUAD5Com5%20gdq6EtgA3Or2sAiGBFDA5qxwHFC0EAwAdmgAtooQIlBcMRpBJdLJ5soiGTlU%20dlQ2CIAljk0peVx4Yk1TFb17FAWVMAtmhPQZbwA9PNQAMYAFlSdEBYrcDkW7cDtu1ROyXH5VGBgnd0QVGtQAEQivtiPZwLAcFAHjJ7LcDQOUmIjAohwzywaCcwHeGjsAgAwrt9odjk4APJoYBgbEAHgAKlAIAAPSZ7TzOVyvDwAPkMxlIRNJ5Isnm8IQMAH54t8GIyoMyyRAKZVOTgecISvzZELWZ5wuKoDz%20rkIAA3YoxIjzABUupIuqgAAk4AB3MbfACSYwgzE2yVW0GWJycymWAGsoAADF6YaHAb1QMEiJoQEGtb6-TxUHKZEShkBQC7ANY3Q2O52A4HFEM4DSeVglO4PODMTNQGjtTVxzq4-P2TBcjMZ%20DFklNMBOCAZuvYhgAbSSpgULDYpVGw-ktRUpQAuhm-QGPi0B95RlKF1BdfMiMwgcs0XGLh6IA4E1QQOLMITicLRVTr7SABR9lKCgdz0Yulzuj0MZ8lxhBhkT2A4jkaTFsXrQlaU-ABKPB6XVOB2gsRCZDIRYoByOAcDzKAywrSIDl2UZFGxKAnDgKtligJ0XmSb4f1OYAnRWV0-zUXgTzPC8rxpTBnyHOQzCYNJGAnQhRNHOpJK4L8oGEqhyLnRDcHpTDSGwm0zVjHAqCYqAikybEoxyZhii2IyTO8TI9mMmzoClAVsIonAOhoVYcFwi1FDw1ZMns7ZFHjaBvTswIpW9bh4JiIA)

```
type FooRequest = {
    _tag: 'foo',
}

type BarRequest = {
    _tag: 'bar',
}

type DurRequest = {
    _tag: 'dur',
}

type AllRequests = FooRequest | BarRequest | DurRequest;

type Foo = { t: 'foo', age: number };
type Bar = { t: 'bar', name: string };
type Dur = { t: 'dur', date: Date };

// chained conditional type mapping each "request" type to it's counterpart "result" type
type ConditionalOutput<T extends AllRequests> = 
    T extends FooRequest ? Foo : 
    T extends BarRequest ? Bar : 
    T extends DurRequest ? Dur : never;

/**
 * How do I define the callback `result` parameter so it's an array matching
 * the counterpart types for each of the given input types?
 * 
 * For example
 * input: [{ _tag: 'foo' }, { _tag: 'bar' }]
 * result type: [Foo, Bar]
 */
function makeArrayRequests<T extends AllRequests>(input: T[], callback: (result: ConditionalOutput<T>[]) => void) {
    // not part of the quesiton, but logic here to call the callback
}


makeArrayRequests([{ _tag: 'foo' }, { _tag: 'bar' }], ([a, b]) => {
    // I want a to be auto infered to be Foo and b to be Bar
    // but right now both a and b are `Foo | Bar`
});
```

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51679156

Comment: @CertainPerformance Perhaps, but my generic skills are failing to adapt it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @CertainPerformance for pointing me to the fancy mapped tuple features, I was able to get something working. But it comes with one little catch, I have to add `as const` to the input parameter.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAShAjgVwgZ2FAvFAbwCgpSoB9YAQwHMAuKAcgDMFGAaIgXyKNEigAhKgCdk6LDnzEyFavSYAjUR269%200ACJoxqDNjyESZSrQaMAJjtU8%204aAEEANk-H7gmQ-CR7JUAD5Com5%20gdq6EtgA3Or2sAiGBFDA5qxwHFC0EAwAdmgAtooQIlBcMRpBJdLJ5soiGTlU%20dlQ2CIAljk0peVx4Yk1TFb17FAWVMAtmhPQZbwA9PNQAMYAFlSdEBYrcDkW7cDtu1ROyXH5VGBgnd0QVGtQAEQivtiPZwLAcFAHjJ7LcDQOUmIjAomAdgEAGFdvtDscnAB5NDAMAogA8ABUoBAAB6TPaeKg5EAAPkMxlI2LxBIsnm8IQMAH54t8GJSoNT8RBCZVGTgWcISuzZFzaZ5wvyoCz%20rkIAA3YoxWICTFoMBOCAAWUukBE6IcOO5vJeVAsuycICgzlcrw8AG0ALrk6Qc%200AST2eJ%20OSgAGsICA4MxrY6GDC9gcjo0kSi0cADR6vbjnTE5kRmEDlvDfRcAw4RCIqCB%20ZgsUbxVBTeacpbrS5S07SQAKTrxhiY0bLE5OZTLP0MZsvTBoJweDvqzU6q7FLGkgCUeHJ8rg7Qsi%20IaiIiygAAMqP9dthdz9PC90O0XttFCifjgAO5wER%20zBEPMQAtFkt2zDN%201JUwFBYNhSlGAD5FqFRSkdTJDxybBRmbeVF1wckZDIAF4OAe0OVkKhRh3bxcLIRQCKWIUORg-B5RiWRMMwOBNQAOicOAaGbKgmKyedaIwo9GIgFi2ObRQmMaZoeO4SSgA)

```
type FooRequest = {
    _tag: 'foo',
}

type BarRequest = {
    _tag: 'bar',
}

type DurRequest = {
    _tag: 'dur',
}

type AllRequests = FooRequest | BarRequest | DurRequest;

type Foo = { t: 'foo', age: number };
type Bar = { t: 'bar', name: string };
type Dur = { t: 'dur', date: Date };

// chained conditional type mapping each "request" type to it's counterpart
type ConditionalOutput<T extends any> = 
    T extends FooRequest ? Foo : 
    T extends BarRequest ? Bar : 
    T extends DurRequest ? Dur : never;


type TupleMapper<A extends readonly AllRequests[]> = {
    [Index in keyof A]: ConditionalOutput<A[Index]>;
};

function makeArrayRequests<T extends readonly AllRequests[]>(input: T, callback: (results: TupleMapper<T>) => void) {

}

// `as const` is required but it works
makeArrayRequests([{ _tag: 'foo' }, { _tag: 'bar' }] as const, (v) => {
    const[
        a, // Foo
        b, // Bar
    ] = v;
    console.log(a.age);
    console.log(b.name);
});
```