# How to map tuples with value | undefined to just value

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a type that map a tuple like this:

```
[number, string | undefined, number | undefined, string | null]
```

to

```
[number, string , number, string]
```

But I am not able to do it.

I tried something like this but obviously does not work

```
type FilterUndefined<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends readonly [infer H, ...infer R] ?
  H extends undefined ? null : [H, ...FilterUndefined<R>] : T
```

[This question sounds similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672504/how-to-map-a-tuple-to-another-tuple-type-in-typescript-3-0), but it extracts from an object.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this was easier that I thought. I forgot about the `NonNullable` helper.

```js
type NotNullableTuple<Tuple extends readonly unknown[]> = {
  [Index in keyof Tuple]: NonNullable<Tuple[Index]>
};
```

:)