# Typescript implementing [Symbol.iterator] with strongly-typed tuple?

Tags: typescript

I want to implement `[Symbol.iterator]` for my typescript class which allows me to have strongly-typed tuple destructuring.

For example, this class stores a strongly-typed tuple internally, which I successfully destructure by accessing the member directly:

```
class Deserializer<ParsedArgs extends Array<unknown> = []> {
  deserialized: ParsedArgs;
  // ...
}

const [str, vec] = (new Deserialized(/* ... */)).deserialized
```

I want to add a `[Symbol.iterator]` implementation so that I can drop the `.deserialized`. I might not actually do this, because it's quite an unexpected API, but is this even possible in typescript?

I tried this, but the individual components end up typed `string | Vector3` for obvious reasons:

```
  [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<ParsedArgs[number]> {
    let index = 0;
    const data = this.deserialized;

    return {
      next: function () {
        return { value: data[++index], done: !(index in data) }
      }
    };
  }
```

[Typescript playground link for below full test code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAahDGwD2AnAzFAvFA2gDwC4oA7AVwFsAjCFAGihCLKpvoC8mLqUBdAbgBQoSFAAiEAM40AlgEMANtLYQASpNLzgAHgAqAPiy4AJpJkKlEI0R31iEAO4B5AGbOpwTi16CBAel9ipihyispQslDyEMQA5sAAFgC0YCgQztJ4llASwMGxAs6kxIjSSMRQJlLB5soAyrnSsQAUAlDhKDESRACCKCiyIABCpK6srVBIru6e3AIAlETiVSEWahIa2jl5MQYA3uPwZTmR0YZ29lAAqo3AaABMvf0gTbIdEgB0EorwEE2TbhBgPR-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-0UhU2nbdAiX86r52FOrhK0+QmkM1VxrQKqoCUtotkaGJJuYliatmxKFqWgq6gaWJ1vlJTCmKYBSnKZaLCaKybPAmgFnahDlGPX9-2NGbynOL6uJ+l7ktwcc4XSpTdxAYoJwte6rTvHI9rjY4rMMWR7FkaQUSaYHBm1SgmhwKT-FRFARyk4HrmIW4HndZ4cDQHg5loKSACJZEoeAuc5imAlUhAaYs4GMyTbNmbJkc7jQd5IQAVgANnoAB2egAA52cFizKa2O5aYxenGafMmld17n4m07UBdGljKZF+AjfFjFJazJmnjJxIR3oRI7n9tmOfGdn3leMC7KJbkHcC3Atj9qBncTw36Gd6doo656rO5CzPgu3bc5Y95VqJKT8+2Mu89L4knuUIxMKgSndyqZH43GW7LXKeAbfgV9dBvHF731bbYigAAfWAEGjNA9L9HRGP2rCjiQKJ3m1XbgCLzb617-vR52JoE6LnuEH71a9OTk+960A+9MN6+z8jafHUvhA7m5JTUeAIkgA)

```
type Vector3 = [x: number, y: number, z: number];
type DeserializeResult<T> = [deserialized: T, newOffset: number];

// Deserialize a length-prefixed string
function deserializeString(
  args: ArrayBuffer,
  offset: number
): DeserializeResult<string> {
  const len = new Uint32Array(args.slice(offset, offset + 4))[0];
  const str = new TextDecoder().decode(
    args.slice(offset + 4, offset + 4 + len)
  );
  return [str, offset + 4 + len];
}

// Deserialize three floats in a row
function deserializeVector3(
  args: ArrayBuffer,
  offset: number
): DeserializeResult<Vector3> {
  const floatArr = new Float32Array(args.slice(offset, offset + 3 * 4));
  const result: Vector3 = [floatArr[0], floatArr[1], floatArr[2]];
  return [result, offset + 3 * 4];
}

class Deserializer<ParsedArgs extends Array<unknown> = []> {
  buffer: ArrayBuffer;
  offset: number;
  deserialized: ParsedArgs;

  constructor(buffer: ArrayBuffer, deserialized: ParsedArgs, offset: number) {
    this.deserialized = deserialized;
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.offset = offset;
  }

  private peel<T>(
    deserializerFunc: (
      buffer: ArrayBuffer,
      offset: number
    ) => DeserializeResult<T>
  ) {
    const [value, offset] = deserializerFunc(this.buffer, this.offset);
    this.offset = offset;
    this.deserialized.push(value);
    return this as unknown as Deserializer<[...ParsedArgs, T]>;
  }

  Vector3() {
    return this.peel(deserializeVector3);
  }

  string() {
    return this.peel(deserializeString);
  }
}

function deserialize(buffer: ArrayBuffer): Deserializer<[]> {
  return new Deserializer(buffer, [], 0);
}

async function test() {
  const buffer = await (new Blob([
    // str1
    new Uint32Array([3]),
    "abc",

    // vec1
    new Float32Array([123.456, 7, 8]),

    // str2
    new Uint32Array([5]),
    "hello",

    // vec2
    new Float32Array([-1, -2, -3]),
  ]).arrayBuffer())


  const [str1, vec1, str2, vec2] = deserialize(buffer)
    .string()
    .Vector3()
    .string()
    .Vector3().deserialized;

  // assertions
  function check<T extends string | Vector3>(t: T) {
    console.log(t)
  }

  check<string>(str1)
  check<Vector3>(vec1)
  check<string>(str2)
  check<Vector3>(vec2)
}

test()
```

Comment: This is not currently possible; there is at least one open feature request asking for support for that, see [ms/TS#42033](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42033). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey, thanks. That fully answers the question. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

As an aside, I was able to make a signature for a similar `deserialize(buffer, ...deserializeFuncs)` that gives the right types (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672504/how-to-map-a-tuple-to-another-tuple-type-in-typescript-3-0), but isn't quite as DX friendly IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible in TypeScript. There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#42033](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42033) to support expressing [generators and iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) that correspond to [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) (fixed lengths, different types, etc) instead of just open-ended same-element [array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays).  There's a similar open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#43150](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43150).  Both of these issues are (as of 2023-11-14) marked as "Awaiting More Feedback" so if you want to see this happen, it wouldn't hurt to go there, give them a  and explain your use case if it's more compelling than what's already in there.  It probably wouldn't *help* much, either, but if enough people do that then there's more of a chance that it will get implemented.